# Using conditionals inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve a check with the `if...else` statement that only squares the odd numbers between 100 and 150, otherwise the number is just printed.

How can I revise my `if` statement to achieve this please? An educated guess is that an operator or combination of operators are used.

```
 for (i=100; i<=150; i++)
    {
        if (i === 0)
        {
            console.log(i * i);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "An *educated* guess is that an operator or combinaton of operators are used." --- thanks, made my morning

Comment: I'm think I am failing to understand the context? Have I managed to be humorous in my attempts to start learning JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you are looking for is `%`:

```
for(i = 100; i <= 150; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 1) { // It's odd
        console.log(i * i);
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

`a % b` is basically the remainder obtained when `a` is divided by `b`. It's called the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.C2.A0.25_%28Modulus%29).

Answer (score 1):

Two words: Modulus Division

[A nice reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( i % 2 === 0) {
  console.log(i)
} else {
  console.log(i * i)
}
```

Squares odd numbers.